Verification Api Google Recaptchav2
I want to use a google recapctha v2 for my portfolio for the email contact. the server request working in local but when i deploy my website it's not working in production, i have a 500 error. The problem may be the configuration of Cloudfare or the way of programming, i don't know. I share my front-end with recpatcha (submitform) and the validation of token in the server. I use Typescript and my recapctha is check when i submit my form with a button
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=6Ld4eToqAAAAAB4UKWnF1O8pTekPlzHcUFzngREH></div>


const submitForm = async (e)=>{
            const recaptchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();
            const divError  = document.getElementById("error-form");
            // Si recpatcha non complété
            if (!recaptchaResponse) {
                divError.innerHTML="<span style=color:red>Veuillez compléter le captcha</span>"
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    divError.innerHTML=""
                },4000)
                return;
            }
            try {
                // Envoie une requête au serveur pour valider le recpatcha
                const response = await fetch('/api/validateRecaptcha', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: 
                        { 'Content-Type':"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" },
                        body: new URLSearchParams({
                            token: recaptchaResponse
                            }).toString()
                });

               
                // Si réponse valide
                const result = await response.json()
                console.log(result)
                if (result.success) {
                    try{
                        // envoie de l'email
                        await sendEmail();
                        divError.innerHTML = "<span style=color:green> Email envoyé avec succès</span>"
                        setTimeout(()=>{
                             divError.innerHTML=""
                        },4000)
                        grecaptcha.reset()
                        e.target.reset()
                    }catch(error){
                        console.log(error)
                        if(error.message=="Email"){
                            divError.innerHTML = "<span style=color:red> Email Incorrect</span>"
                            setTimeout(()=>{
                                divError.innerHTML=""
                            },4000)
                            grecaptcha.reset()
                        }
                        else{
                            divError.innerHTML = "<span style=color:red> Erreur lors de l'envoie de l'email</span>"
                            setTimeout(()=>{
                                divError.innerHTML=""
                            },4000)
                            grecaptcha.reset()
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    divError.innerHTML = "<span style=color:red>Erreur validation du Recaptcha</span>"
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                        divError.innerHTML=""
                    },4000)
                    grecaptcha.reset();
                }
            } catch (error) 
            {
                grecaptcha.reset()
                console.error(error);
            }
        }

the validateRecaptcha.ts
import { defineEventHandler, readBody } from 'h3';
import axios from 'axios';

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const body = await readBody(event);
  const { token } = body;
  const secret : string | undefined = process.env.RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY;

  if (!token) {
    return { success: false, message: 'No token provided' };
  }
  if(!secret){
    return {sucess : false, message : 'No key provided'}
  }

  try {
    const result  = await axios.post(
      `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${encodeURIComponent(secret)}&response=${encodeURIComponent(token)}`
    );

    const data = result.data || {};

    if (!data.success) {
      throw {
        success: false,
        error: 'Response not valid'
      };
    }

    return data;  // Retourner les données reçues

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err.response ? err.response.data : { success: false, error: 'captcha_error' };
  }
});

I try to change the domain, the keys and the way to send the request api but isn't working
